# Excel.Range.Find using a string longer than 255 characters

Tags: c#, excel

I'm storing strings with 1023 characters each inside of Excel. At a later point I need to be able to search through the excel file and find what row a value is in.  I can guarantee that exactly one occurrence of the string I'm looking for will exist somewhere in the workbook.

Currently I get a type Mismatch error every time I try to search (due to the length limit of 255 on the find function).  When I replace my search string with something short like "teststring", it works fine.  How can I search for a 1023 character string in Excel?

```
foreach (string missingItem in missingItems)
{
    Range currentFind = null;
    foreach (Worksheet searchSheet in oWB.Worksheets)
    {
        Range lookAtRange = (Range)searchSheet.get_Range ("A1", "F20");

        currentFind = lookAtRange.Find (
            missingItem, 
            Missing.Value, 
            XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
            Missing.Value,
            Missing.Value, 
            XlSearchDirection.xlNext, 
            false, 
            false,
            Missing.Value);

        if (currentFind != null)
        {
            Range deleteRow = (Range)searchSheet.Rows[currentFind.Row];
            deleteRow.Delete (XlDirection.xlUp);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-9179.html

In short, if all your strings are unique for the first 255 characters, you don't need to worry about the rest.

You just need to truncate the string before you perform a find on it:

```
missingItem = Left(missingItem,255)
```

or alternatively:

```
missingItem = Right (missingItem,255)
```

Otherwise, if there are many duplicates of the first 255 characters, you could divide the string by 255 - then round up - then split the original string into seperate strings, search them individualy - does that help you?

EDIT:

Otherise, here is how you can check a string for equivalency for each cell in a range:
http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=167

```
Sub FindIt()
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim SearchString As String
    For Each Cell In Range("A1:D500")
        If Cell.Value = "dqwlokjdowqijowqijdoinowiqhdoiwqiophiruegnqpiunrgpiuqgnrgkjffndskfiougpiodghiudhfgtothisansdfldkjflsdffjlksdjflksjfdoiejwfoiwjeoinfoinewoifjwoiejfoiwejfoiwejfoijjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjwerkjwelkfjwelkjflkwejlfkjwelkjflwkjeflknweoifnoweinfoinewfoinoifwnwoienfoinweoddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfinwoioiefldkjsfoijoneiojfoijfewwefweeeeeeeeeeeefwef" Then '<< use "Like" for wildcards in If-Then statements
            MsgBox "An ''it'' was found at " & Cell.Address & " (" & Cell & ")"
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

[image: Funny Search String]

And yes I did pretend to type that as something important as my boss walked by. I don't think he was fooled though - since I just mashed it out on my keyboard.

Comment: The values I'm looking for are unique IDs, and I will need to match on all 1023 characters. I could get the location of all the matches of the first 255 characters, then retrieve the value and search through those, but that seems incredibly inefficient. I'll use this for now, but I'm hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: If they are going to be exactly the same, you could just forget about .find and just check for each cell if they match missingItem. .find seems to me to be meant more for doing a quick search for specific words - not to check equivalency between things.

Comment: The first 255 characters may be the same, they may not be. I won't know. I will have an ID that I'm looking for, and there will be somewhere between 1 and 1000 of these IDs spread out between several worksheets. That is why I was hoping the find function would be of some use.

Comment: I would use a custom find function like the one in my edit. Obviously, for your purposes, instead of return the Cell.Address you would probably want to return the Cell.Row.