# Runtime error 13 - Type Mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I have following code. Here, newSearchText is more than 500 character string. I get 'Runtime error 13 - Type Mismatch' when I run VBA macro.

```
            Set Rng = Cells.Find(What:=newSearchText, _
                              After:=.Cells(1), _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            matchcase:=matchvalue)
```

How do I handle it?

Comment: Drop the dot before `Cells(1)`

Comment: It is best to handle it by correcting whatever it is that is causing the error.  If that cannot be done, then you will need an error handling routine.  One item that looks odd to me:  What is `matchvalue`?

Comment: It still gives the same error. It runs well when the length of 'newSearchText' string is less than 163. 'newSearchText'  has Japanese Characters too

Comment: `matchvalue` is boolean value to decide whether to match the value if it has Japanese chars

Comment: I've not used the `Range.Find` method with Unicode characters, but perhaps you should consider the `matchbyte` argument rather than the `matchcase` argument.  At least the HELP description of `matchcase` would not seem to be applicable.  And I don't know if you have double-byte character support installed.

Comment: Also, at least in older versions of Excel, the string length for `What` was limited to 255 characters. May be different for double byte characters.  I dunno about the later versions.  Perhaps [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724067/excel-range-find-using-a-string-longer-than-255-characters) will help.

Comment: `matchbyte` generates the same error

Comment: If you want your macro to handle non-ascii, you need to make change to your Windows: "Language for non-Unicode programs" to match your desired language. In your case, you need to change the system locale to Japanese. Reboot and your VBA `.Find` will find Japanese characters. Otherwise, the text will turn into question marks.

Comment: yes, my locale is Japanese. My whole system is in Japanese language only. Chatacters are being replaced as well. Issue only arises when the length become more than 160 odd.

Comment: Further research suggests the length of the `what` argument is limited to 255 ASCII characters; so probably less with Japanese characters.  The article I cited in my previous comment gives some suggestions as to how to cope.