# Handle more than 255 characters in what:= attribute of Cells.find()

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

Here `newStr` has sometimes more than 255 chars, and then it gives Type 13, mismatch error. Any suggestion ? I am aware that it is not possible in Office 2007 or below, how about later versions?

```
Set Variable = Cells.Find(What:=newStr, _
                          After:=.Cells(1), _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        matchcase:=yesno)
```

Comment: Use the first 255 characters in the find, then test each found cell against the full value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel.Range.Find using a string longer than 255 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724067/excel-range-find-using-a-string-longer-than-255-characters).  Although the question has to do with C#, the answer has a useful VBA solution.

Comment: so even in excel 2007/13/1, will I have to do the same?